# WooCommerce URL to filter by attribute

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I am trying to find out the URL I need to display products on my shop page based on an attribute. The attribute is called "**Mantel Type**" (slug **mantel-type**) and the term is "**Mantel With Overmantel**" (slug **mantel-with-overmantel**). The term has an ID of **106**. I've tried the following URLs, but all products are displayed, rather than the expected 22, or I get a 404 error.

mysite.com/shop/?attribute_mantel-type=Mantel+With+Overmantel

mysite.com/shop/?attribute_mantel-type=mantel-with-overmantel

mysite.com/shop/?taxonomy=pa_mantel-type?&tag_ID=106

mysite.com/shop/?filter_mantel-type=106

mysite.com/shop/?filter_mantel-type=Mantel+With+Overmantel

mysite.com/shop/?filter_mantel-type=mantel-with-overmantel

mysite.com/shop/?pa_mantel-type=Mantel+With+Overmantel (404 error)

mysite.com/shop/?pa_mantel-type=106 (404 error)

I have made sure that the enable archives checkbox has been selected in the Mantel Type attribute editor.

I've had success with product categories, just not attributes. This product category link works, for example:

mysite.com/shop/?product_cat=french

How can I include attributes in the URL as well? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Woocommerce attributes are just Wordpress taxonomies.

https://example.com/mantel-type/mantel-with-overmantel/ will get what you want. I imagine there is some way to get https://tart.dolcedev.com/shop/mantel-type/mantel-with-overmantel/ to go to what you want but I don't know enough about your wp setup to help with that.

You can also use `get_term_link` to generate these urls dynamically. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/

The urls with the "?" all go to the "shop" page. Anything in a url preceded by a ? is just a query string.

Comment: Thanks! That does work, but I need to display a combination of attribute + category filters at once...can I get the non-pretty version? The query URL? Also, can you please do me a favour and replace your urls with "mysite"? I'm trying to protect the identity of the site.

Comment: of course! replaced. you cant really do that with slugs as far as i know... they are specific to single terms. And wordpress uses the query to get things, not a query url. You have some filter plugin (or possibly native woocommerce filters?) on the "shop" page that are generating those but for the archive pages wordpress runs the query. I'd recommend building a custom archive page template for the different combinations of things you need. You'd have to build out a separate one for each combination though.